# Are there toilets on the Stradbroke Island ferry?

Tags: australia, ferries, brisbane

There is a cafe on a few of the ferries but a toilet is not mentioned.

Are there toilet facilities on the Stradbroke Island ferry?

If not, is there one at the ferry station - one that can be used before getting on the ferry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this August 21, 2016 [review](https://www.facebook.com/dani.harriott/posts/10154460824431202:0)

> What's the go with the same price to have no access to a bathroom, no viewing deck and $10 to change the time (not advised of this charge when booking, might be a good heads up) - if your going to take away some of the comforts you ought to take away some of the price!

There seems to be no bathroom on the ferry.

According to this [review](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowUserReviews-g494983-d6522310-r414375565-Stradbroke_Ferries_Pty_Ltd-Cleveland_Redland_City_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html) however,

> The Cleveland office also has a good little cafe and toilet.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about the car ferries, than yes there are toilets on them (even the older models). Look for signs upstairs in the cafe area.

Source: am local and have traveled on this ferry many times.